# Calculate the sides of a 2d polygon from the vertices?

Tags: java, math, vector, polygon, trigonometry

So how would I go about calculating the sides of a 2d polygon?
They're non-concave poly's, by the way.

Comment: How about http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: What is the input? polygon name? interior angle for regular polygon?

Comment: @Rasika, What's *polygon name*? Like "triangle"?

Comment: @Rasika:  This seems to be a case of putting an essential part of the question in the subject line... "from the vertices".

Answer (score 1):

If the polygon is non-concave, i.e., convex, you should look at some convex-hull algorithm.

There are plenty at the wikipedia article: [Wikipedia: Convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for doing a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). There are many [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) you can use to calculate it.